# ¿Cual es la manera mas optima de hacer un ciclo infinito en bash?

Tags: bash, while, shell

Se me ocurre algo como:

```sh
# Quiero que se ejecute un daemon hasta que se pulse control + c 
trap 'handle_exit 0' SIGINT

# El ciclo solo es para esperar que pulsen ctrl + c
while true
do
    sleep 1000000
done
```

Ahora bien, quiero saber si hay una forma mas limpia para hacer ese ciclo.

Comment: `while :` y ya.

Comment: ¿Sin el sleep, ni el do ni el done?, explicate xd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente hazlo correr para siempre ejecutando una no-acción:

```
trap 'handle_exit 0' SIGINT

# El ciclo solo es para esperar que pulsen ctrl + c
while true
do
    :  # <--- esto no hace nada, es como un "pass" en Python
done
```